# Classifiers for rooms

Tags: measure-word

What is the best classifier to use for rooms?

> 一 ***_*____** 卧室
>
> 两 ***_*___**_客厅
>
> 三 ***_*___**_洗衣房

What about houses or buildings?

I know there is 一层楼 for a floor / level / story of a building, what about the building itself?

How about classifiers for collections of buildings like in English "a block of houses"?

Are there any other classifiers for building / rooms I should be aware of?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Technically, you would use 间 for all rooms: 一间卧室 (a bedroom), 一间书房 (a study).

间 can refer to larger spaces as well in Mandarin spoken in Taiwan and Cantonese: 一间学校 (a school), 一间饭店 (a restaurant), 一间房子 (a house/apartment). Note that mainland China accepts this usage now and you can hear 一间饭店/学校 in the news.

There is also the trend to simplify all classifiers to 个 where possible. 一个卧室, 两个客厅, 三个洗衣房, 四个房子 all sound right to me, and are perhaps more common than 间.

To avoid repeating "间", the classifier for 房间 (room) is often 个: 一个房间, 两个房间. (You hear 一间房间 as well.)

A house: 一间房子/一个房子; a building: 一个大楼 (Note that the Chinese live in apartments, so 房子 usually refers to apartments.)

Block is 街区. 时尚街区 and 高品质街区 are seen in the ads nowadays. But again, we don't live in houses, so 小区 (neighborhood/community) is more common.